Triangulations of manifolds are non-branching
Let $X$ be an $n$-manifold and let $K$ be a triangulation of that manifold. I am looking for a proof of the fact that $K$ is non-branching, which means:
There is no simplex $S \in K$ of dimension $n-1$ that lies in the intersectia on of three different simplices $T_1, T_2, T_3 \in K$ of dimension $n$.
This is an "obvious" fact, however, I have not found a proof in the literature. I presume one possibly approach uses the connectivity properties of local stars together with the fact that the manifold is locally Euclidean. I hope to find an easier proof here but I would be grateful for a literature references as well.

That looks like it should be part of the definition of a triangulation. So if you show that a triangulation exists, then your construction needs to check for that. If you already have a triangulation, this is a given.

Absolutely not part of the definition but a consequence. There are triangulations that don't satisfy the property (and which don't triangulate manifolds). What triangulation of a manifold become possible if you "allow" branching?

I have seen this property as an exercise. But I disagree that it is obvious and I would like to find a proper proof.

Hint: Look at the local homology for a generic point in $S$.

@MoisheKohan: I am afraid that hint is not enough.

Do you know how to compute local homology groups  $H_*(X,X-x)$ for manifolds $X$? This is covered on any standard algebraic topology course.
